# How do I call tagit("destroy") to remove tags?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, tag-it

On clicking the Clear Query Box link (id clearQueryBox) I want to call the tagit("destroy") method to empty the tags. This is because sometimes users are copy and pasting about 10 tags at a time to do a search so will be easier for them if they can clear al tags at once rather than backspacing twenty times or clicking the mini x ten times. I've got this:

```
$('#query').tagit({
    select: true,
    allowNewTags: true,
    triggerKeys: ['enter', 'comma', 'tab'],
    placeholder: '',
    tagsChanged: function () {
        $("#clearQueryBox").click(function () {
            $("#query").tagit("destroy");
        });
    }
});
```

I keep getting the error 'cannot call methods on tagit prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'destroy''. I am using Halewood's jQuery tagit (https://github.com/hailwood/jQuery-Tagit). It defines tagit("destroy") as a method.

Answer (score 2):

Now i know this probably a little late, but this is maybe for any incoming viewers.

```
$("#query").tagit("removeAll");
```

reference link [here](http://aehlke.github.io/tag-it/examples.html) .

Answer (score 1):

To remove all the tags on Jquery could use **jQuery remove () Method**

`$(selector).remove(selector)` or `$(selector).hide(selector)`

implementation in your code

```
$("#query").tagit("tags").remove();
```

or

```
$("#query").tagit("tags").hide();
```

I hope this is what you need.

Comment: I'm just getting tagsChanged — tagit.php:26TypeError: $("#query").tagit("tags").remove is not a function. (In '$("#query").tagit("tags").remove()', '$("#query").tagit("tags").remove' is undefined)